# How can I create a code if I need to delete some record using In parameter in android?

Tags: android

Normally I can use the following code to delete a recod.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("test.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);  
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person");  
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE person (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, age SMALLINT)");  
db.delete("person", "id = ?", new String[]{"35"});
```

Now I hope to delete some records, the sql just like

```
delete from test.db where id in ('6','4')
```

How can I write the code?
Is `db.delete("person", "id in ?", new String[]{'6','4'} )` right?

Answer (score 0):

> public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

`delete` method description is quite clear. If you want to **delete** a row of the given id then it should be something like this:

```
db.delete("person", "id="+String.valueOf(int_id_to_delete), null);
```

Futher, if you want to delete multiple rows at once use the following:

```
 db.delete("person", "id"+"=?", new String[]{"6","4"});
```

Comment: Thanks! what sql code will be created by system when I use db.delete("person", "id"+"=?", new String[]{"6","4"});

Comment: This will delete rows of id 6 and 4 from the table person. I don't know what sql code it creates... Do you really need to know this?

Comment: Thanks! I don't know system how to differentiate Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable where numberType=? and id=?", new String[] { "2","5" });

Comment: Maybe you are wrong, would you please to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726759/how-does-the-sqlitedatabase-to-distinguish-parameters-for-one-var-or-two-vars-in

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code or can execute a raw query as android permits.

```
db.delete("person", "id"+ "=?", new String[] {"4","6"});
```