# How does the SQLiteDatabase to distinguish parameters for one var or two vars in android?

Tags: android

Somebody told me:
In the following code, the parameter "2" is for var numberType and the parameter "5" is for var id

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable where numberType=? and id=?", new String[] { "2","5" });
```

In the following code, both the parameter "6" and the parameter "4" are for var id.
I think the code will cause error, I think new String[]{"6","4"} must match two vars, right?

```
db.delete("person", "id"+"=?", new String[]{"6","4"});
```

I can't **use db.delete (...)** to implement the same function just like **delete from test.db where id in ('6','4')!**  right ?

[How can pass two parameters to rawQuery in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723403/how-can-pass-two-parameters-to-rawquery-in-android)
[How can I create a code if I need to delete some record using In parameter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701049/how-can-i-create-a-code-if-i-need-to-delete-some-record-using-in-parameter-in-an)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the code will cause error, I think new String[]{"6","4"} must
>   match two vars, right?

*Short answer:* Yes. This piece of code won't work.

### Explanation:

You want to bind two parameters - in other words you want to replace two placeholders **`?`** with bindArgs<sup>1</sup> (in your case number 6 and 4).

Number of parameters in statement have to match number of parameters binded to statement - so if you have **three parameters** in query (otherwise Exception will be thrown):

```
select * from Users where id = ? and age = ?
```

You have to create **whereArgs** string-array with same number of parameters (items):

```
String[] whereArgs = {"20345", "18"};
```

> How does the SQLiteDatabase to distinguish parameters for one var or
>   two vars in android?

Explained above. Correct solutions for your case are:

- add second parameter to `WHERE` clause
- remove second item from string-array

It can looks like:

```
db.delete("person", "id = ? and pin = ?", new String[] {"6", "4"});
db.delete("person", "id = ?", new String[] {"6"});
db.delete("person", "id in(?, ?)", new String[] {"6", "4"});
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>Replacing is same like in classic Java: first parameter in query will be replaced with first item in array etc.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! does it mean I can't use **db.delete (...)** to implement the same function just like **delete from test.db where id in ('6','4')** ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this eg. **db.execSQL("DELETE  from tablename where id IN (1,2)");** Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete from the same table as follows.

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (
    SELECT pid FROM (
        SELECT person.id AS pid FROM person) AS ptable
    )
```

Now, you can change the nested queries as per your need.

PS: I have written this just to give you a direction.

Comment: Thanks! does it mean I can't use db.delete (...) to implement the same function just like delete from test.db where id in ('6','4') ?

Comment: You can't use db.delete method to accomplish this task, rawQuery is an option.